# How to implement flick gesture in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have a `UIImageView` and I want to implement a flick feature like this  link [iOS gesture](https://developer.apple.com/carplay/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/touchscreen/). I tried with a `UISwipeGestureRecoginizer` but it does not have the velocity. I also tried with `UIScrollView` and added the `UIImageView` to it, but the scroll is slower like pan, not like flick. My code is as below.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
[scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];`
```

Comment: I need to flick up and down only, no zoom.

Comment: I don't think you can get speed faster than uiscrollview. Have a look on `scrollView.decelerationRate`

Comment: I have tried but it does not work because I find that my scrollview does not scroll.

Comment: Set your contentSize if scroll view has same size as parent view it will not scroll until you set its contentsize.